# Problems using .htaccess to make some pages secure and some unsecure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using .htaccess to make the membership renewal pages on my Drupal site secure, but I'm having trouble switching back to regular http when the user navigates away from that page. The page that should be secure is:

www.example.com/renew

I want everything else to use http, and I'm trying the following redirects to achieve this:

```
# Renewal page should be secure. Redirect.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew$ https://www.example.com/renew [R,L]

# If user leaves the Renewal page, make sure we're no longer secure. Redirect.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^renew$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I got the first redirect working fine. When I added the second, unsecure redirect, it breaks the first redirect -- Firefox says there's a redirect loop.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` is a variable that **always** starts with a `/`. Due to this, the second condition of the second rule will always be true, as `%{REQUEST_URI}` will never be equal to `^renew$`. To fix this, change that condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/renew$
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks for the help, Sumurai8.